# mediaelement.js not working when called after AJAX in IE8

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, mediaelement.js

I have an absolutely crazy-making bug going on in IE8. At the moment, the following code works everywhere but IE8.

If I run this in chrome, with the alerts enabled "success" fires.
If I run it in IE "error" does.

Sadly, in IE I can't seem to track down any sort of verbose error message.

Is there anyone who has figured this out?  I'm going bonkers trying to figure it out.

```
<?php
function the_ajax(){
$video_embed =  "<video id='myvideo' width='$videowidth' height='$videoheight' poster='$large' controls='controls' preload='none'>
    <source type='video/mp4' src='$videomp4' />
    <source type='video/webm' src='$videowebm' />
    <source type='video/ogg' src='$videoogg' />
    <object width='$videowidth' height='$videoheight' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='$siteroot/js/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf'>
    <param name='movie' value='$siteroot/js/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf' />
    <param name='flashvars' value='controls=true&file=$videomp4' />
    <img src='$large' width='$videowidth' height='$videoheight' title='No video playback capabilities' />
    </object>
</video>";
echo $video_embed;
}
?>
```

and the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_my_video&name='+thevideo, 
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    contentArea.html(response);
    $("#myvideo").mediaelementplayer({
        enablePluginDebug: true,
        plugins:["flash","silverlight"],
        type: '',
        pluginPath: "/js/mediaelement/",
        flashName:  "flashmediaelement.swf",
        silverlightName: 'silverlightmediaelement.xap',
        success:function(mediaElement, domObject) { 
                //alert('success');
        },
        error: function () { 
            GLOBAL_ERR = this;
            //alert('unknown error');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Incidentally, the "sample output" in IE8 shows the POSTER IMAGE stacked on top of a large block of white space.  If you right click the white space it will say "about flash" etc... so it seems to be that the flash player isn't actually initializing.

**EDIT**
I have found a way to get the video playing - (wooo!) but the poster/flas is still stacked.
The key to getting the video playing in IE8 is changing the opening VIDEO tag.  Add `src='$videomp4'` to the opening  tag.

```
 <video id='myvideo' width='$videowidth' height='$videoheight' poster='$large' controls='controls' preload='none' src='$videomp4'>
```

**EDIT2**

As it turns out removing everything from `<object` to `</object>` actually fixes the layout issue in IE8.  Videos seem to be playable in Chrome, F, FF3.6 & IE8

I haven't tested anything else and I worry that I've lost something somewhere... but for everything I've tested this seems to be working.

Comment: Thank you for posting your updates, finding help with `mediaelement.js` is currently quite difficult.

Comment: Please turn your answer into a real answer below. You can mark it as accepted after two days. That will make the question go away from the Unanswered Questions tab.

Comment: Please don't use the question title for metadata. That's reserved for the system itself - thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I don't understand what you are asking, or what alternative you would have preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out removing everything from `<object>` to `</object>` actually fixes the layout issue in IE8. Videos seem to be playable in Chrome, FF3.6 & IE8

I haven't tested anything else and I worry that I've lost something somewhere... but for everything I've tested this seems to be working.

Comment: Don't forget to use the appropriate markdown or we can't see your code.